# Построить график функции с++ (WinAPi)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Стоит задача:построить график функции на координатной плоскости при помощи WInApi.
С WinApi сталкиваюсь первый раз.
Пробовал пока строить без осей координат,лишь бы график появился.
Использовал SetPixel ,но не получилось.

Вот код,который пишу в разделе WM_PAINT

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

for (int i =300; i < 400; i++)
{
    int y;
    y= i * i*i - 10 * i*i - 3 * i + 59;
    SetPixel(hdc,i+50,y,RGB(0,100,255));
}

EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

Выводит 4 точки,надеюсь заметите их.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?Может я в корне не правильно подхожу к построению на WinAPi ?

Comment: Да, я не раз писал подобное, только делал, и советую `LineTo` использовать, т.к. мелкая дельта - замедления в вычислениях, и невсегда можно мелкую дельту сделать. Т.е. если рисуете точки - получите точки. Если рисуете линии  - получите линию. Всё логично.

Answer (score 2):

Тут явно отсутствует проверка на то, что получившиеся координаты `x` `y` остаются в пределах окна. Первое же значение `y` при `i` = 300 будет `26099159`. Соответственно тут надо делать масштабирование чтоб они влезали в нужный диапазон.

Answer (score 1):

Я начинающий, поэтому могу ошибаться. В y записывается нормализированное значение от 0 до 1. В данном случае используется отсчет от верхнего левого края окна и ось y направлена вниз. В функции SetPixel +200 отвечает за смещение начала графика вниз(при 0 график будет начинаться на верхней границе окна и в данном случае расти вверх, т.е. его не будет видно). Умножение на -1 делает график растущим вверх. 500 это коэффициент, который я подобрал эмпирическим путем.

```
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        for(int i = 300; i <= 400; ++i)
        {
            double y = (double)(i * i * i - 10 * i * i - 3 * i + 59 - 26099159)/(62398859-26099159);
            SetPixel(hdc, i, (int)(y*(-1*500)+200), RGB(0,100,255));
        }
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

Comment: "В программировании используется отсчет от верхнего левого края окна и ось y направлена вниз" - неправда. Это зависит от конкретного API.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 1):

1  Найти минимальные и максимальные значения аргумента (это просто края отрезка X0, X1) и функции на заданном отрезке

2  Рассчитать коэффициенты для преобразования значений в координаты, исходя из размеров прямоугольника вывода

```
  Y_Coeff = (Y_Max - Y_Min) /  (Func_Max - Func_Min)
```

3  Для графического режима по умолчанию `MM_TEXT`  Y-ось направлена вниз, поэтому координаты для `Y = F(X)`:

```
Y_Coord = YMax - (Y-  Func_Min)* Y_Coeff
X_Coord = XMin + (X - X0) * X_Coeff
```

4 Чтобы лучше было видно, рисовать с помощью `LineTo`